# Job description for german blue card

Tags: blue-card

I have an upcoming appointment at Embassy for German Blue card. I have all the required documents except for Job description. The employer is on summer vacations and I am unable to reach him. Is it possible that I use the Job description mentioned in the Job advertisement. Or should I ask HR for stellenbeschreibung since they have applied for ZAV approval and sent me the  Erklärung zum Beschäftigungsverhältnis, or should I cancel the appointment (I have already confirmed)